# Adobe sign API - create a widget with pre-filling details

Tags: rest, adobe, adobe-sign

I'm trying to implement the functionality, where users need to sign documents within the application process instead of sending a document to user for eSignature.

I used Adobe Sign API(using trail account) to achieve this and was able to create a widget and get the embedded code to display the document in the HTML page successfully.

But, while creating the widget I wanted to prefill the form fields and set field as read-only(first_name, address etc) in the document. I'm not able to access/customize form filed.

steps, I followed to achieve this.

- Create transientDocument using Form(4506_T). `POST - /transientDocuments`
- Create a widget using transientDocumentId. `POST - /widgets`
- Get embeddedCode in the widget views call response. `POST /widgets/{widgetId}/views`

But there is something called mergeFieldInfo in create widget model in (API- v5). It'll help to set a default value but there is no attribute to set field as read-only.

I have searched about this in Adobe forums but cannot find the solution.

*API version I have tried- [V6](https://secure.in1.echosign.com/public/docs/restapi/v6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make field read-only and prefilling fields with value.

First, we have to customize our PDF template before creating transient document.
After creating transient document, We can set field value using `mergeFieldInfo` in create widget API.

1. Customize our pdf form field using [Adobe Sign - Creating Forms within Acrobat](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/sign/help/adobesign_acrobat_forms.html)
2. To prefill data using the text tag [Adobe Sign text tag](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/sign/help/adobesign_text_tag_guide.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution

- You can create a Web Form/Widget in Adobe Sign with a meaningful field names and pre-fill those field values in url as parameters
- Steps

  - In the field properties, check the `Read only` and `Default value may come from url` checkboxes, Refer this screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqSqs.png

    - NOTE : Field Type should be `Text Input`
  - Save the web form, you will get the widget url
  - Assume your web form url look like this

```
https://secure.in1.adobesign.com/public/esignWidget?wid=CBF2s*
```

- Add your parameters

  - The start of the parameters are identified by adding a hash (pound, #) symbol at the end of the web form URL.
  - Then add the parameters in the format of {field_name}={value}
    Example URL with one parameter

```
https://secure.na1.echosign.com/public/esignWidget?wid=CBF2s*#Branch_Office=San Jose #621
```

- Multiple values are added by inserting an ampersand (&) between field values.
  Example URL with two parameters

```
https://secure.na1.echosign.com/public/esignWidget?wid=CBF2s*#Branch_Office=San Jose #621&Emp_ID=429939
```

- Once all of the field=value pairs are added to the URL, copy the full string and paste it into your browser, the web form will render with the fields populated

> Check Official Documentation for reference :
> https://helpx.adobe.com/in/sign/using/web-forms.html