# Adobe Sign creating widget from transient document. Attempting to retrieve view for signing returning VIEW_NOT_AVAILABLE

Tags: rest, widget, adobe, sign, echosign

I am implementing functionality to present a document to the end user to sign inside my web application.
The documented steps to accomplish this are:

- Create transientDocument POST -  {url}/transientDocuments
- Create a widget using transientDocumentId. POST - {url}/widgets
- Get embeddedCode in the widget views call response. POST - {url}/widgets/{widgetId}/views

The post body indicates what view to return
{
  "name": "ALL"(ALL, SIGNING, etc..)
}

When I execute my code with 'ALL', the views call does not return the SIGNING view and when I specifically request the SIGNING view, i get the "VIEW_NOT_AVAILABLE: Requested view is not available for the resource in the current state." response.

I can successfully run the request in the Adobe test environment and can even get my code to succeed immediately after a successful request in the test harness, but stand alone and, more importantly, when I deploy my code, I get the Error noted above.

I have searched for the past two days and cannot find anything on this specific error.
This link is the closest I can find to anything dealing woith this issue: [Adobe sign API - create a widget with pre-filling details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52291229/adobe-sign-api-create-a-widget-with-pre-filling-details)

I have verified my Scopes are correct in my OAuth token and that my OAuth settings on my test account match what is expected in my Authorization Token.

I am at a total loss.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if you are creating the widget in correct state?

Only in ACTIVE state of widget you can obtain its SIGNING view. It could be the case that the widget you created is in DRAFT or AUTHORING state and hence getting the error "VIEW_NOT_AVAILABLE".

If thats not the case, please share the request you used in widget creation to troubleshoot further.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. As it turns out there is a delay of about 3 seconds before the SIGNING view is ready to be retrieved. If you delay code execution for 3 seconds before fetching the view you should be able to get it. Not a perfect solution, but my interaction with Adobe's support has been less than helpful so far.

Adobe's reply:

> A delay of 2 to 3 seconds is to be expected while the Adobe Sign
> system processes your uploaded files & generates a publicly accessible
> URL. Please modify your app so that there's a delay between the widget
> being uploaded & the attempt to retrieve its signing URL from our
> servers.